# How to remove the line/rule of an axis in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I managed to remove all horizontale lines/rules in my chart using this:

```
scales: {
       xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display: false
        }  
    }]
}
```

But I also want to get rid of the rule/bar that represents the Y-axis as well. *But I want to keep the labels*:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't find any option for that. I can only remove the whole axis including labels.

I'm using Chart.js 2.3.

Comment: in x axis gridLines u make it as false and looking in the y axis to display the false

Comment: @Parthasarathy The example show ho to remove the horizontal gridlines. But this option doesn't remove the actual line for the axis (horizontally or vertically doesn't matter). So I'm looking for an option how to remove the actual line of the axis not only the grid lines.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found a way to remove this line. It's actually called the `border` of the axis and there's an option for it, see ["Grid Line Configuration"](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration):

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: This doesnot work. DownVoted because of that (sorry)
this code worked for me: 
gridLines: {
                        display:false
                    }  

Update it and I will upvote again!

Comment: worked for me, I already had display:none but was not sufficient for that borders. thanks

Comment: Doesn't work in v.2.9.0, but fixed in v.3.0.0 https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6876

Answer (score 5):

In **v3** you can do:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        drawBorder: false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/styling#grid-line-configuration

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
 options: {
     scales: {
          yAxes: [{
               gridLines: {
                  display: false,
              }
          }]
     },
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in version 2.8.0 -

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            tickMarkLength: false,
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The left line is still coming from the x axis grid lines. Changing the 'zeroLineColor' of the x axis to 'transparent' hid it.

```
xAxes:[{
gridLines:{
zeroLineColor:'transparent'
}}]
```

Source: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3950

Answer (score 2):

In the version 4.x.x you do it like this:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
       border: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    x: {
      grid: {
        drawOnChartArea: false,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

The border in y is the option that specifically does what you are asking. I added the x for users that also want to see how to hide the rest of the x axis lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridLines: {zeroLineColor: 'transparent'}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26055927)

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.

Comment: @john An answer that's not fully explained, incomplete, or just plain wrong is still an answer. If you think it's a *bad* answer, that's what downvotes are for. See [when to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1324)

Answer (score 0):

this workerd for me
`yAxes: [ { gridLines: { display: false, }, }, ],`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in v4.4

---

```
scales: {
x: {
  border: {
    display: false,
  },
},
y: {
  border: {
    display: false,
  },
}
```

---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `scaleLineColor: 'transparent'` it will remove the y any x axis

Comment: This will remove the labels as well, right? The labels should stay. Only the *line* should be gone.

Comment: you want to remove both the axis lines?

Comment: Actually only the Y-axis line. Is this a global setting? I can't find it in the Chart.js docs.

Comment: new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: false
            }]
        }
    }
}); please have a look on the link it will help you http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-chart-options

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - I found an option to remove the line, which is actually the "´border`" option of the gridlines.

Comment: ha ha ha okie thank you.. give the support flag to my comment :P