# How to remove the Chart.js x Axis bottom line?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using Chart.js 2.8.0 trying to get rid of the X/Y axis border.
With `gridLines { showBorder: false }}` I am still seeing the X axis border.
I also have the color set to 0 alpha, all the other lines on X and Y are gone except for the bottom one on the X axis that just wont go away.
Tries some other options like `drawBorder: false` and `scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",` none affected the bottom line on the X axis.
[image]

This is my chart configurations

```
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: '',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: [],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        layout: {
            padding: {
            top: 20
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            gridLines: {
                showBorder: false
            },
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    display: false,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the line/rule of an axis in Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522923/how-to-remove-the-line-rule-of-an-axis-in-chart-js)

Comment: No. As stated above, I have used the solution in that question unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some time fiddling with it I have found the solution zeroLineColor: 'transparent' did the trick. Found it here https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3950

```
scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: 'transparent'
                },
            }],
```

Answer (score 9):

For anyone looking for the answer in v5, it's:
`options.scales.x.border.display: false;`

Comment: I am someone who was looking for the answer in v5! Thank you! This works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone is on v3 and is looking for the answer, its `options.scales.x.grid.drawBorder: false`

This is on v3.7.1 Found it by complete accident by looking through the typescript file and trying anything that looked relevant.

Answer (score 1):

this answer for who are using recharts module :

```
<XAxis strokeOpacity={0} dataKey="name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone looking for answer with ChartJS v4 then try this

```js
scales: {
y: {
 border: {
  display: false
  }
 }
}
```